# How to generate XML sitemap for a Single Page App?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, single-page-application, sitemap

I need to generate an XML sitemap for a Single Page App (vuejs). Avarage sitemap generators don't work in this case because they don't execute any Javascript, so they cannot see the real content of the page. As I searched the web for a solution, I found that botmap.io is the right choice in this case, but right now, the url botmap.io gives a 403 error response. As an alternative solution I found a sitemap generator for vuejs, but that only generates a static sitemap from the router configuration and does not include my dynamic contents.

Are there any alternatives to botmap.io?

Comment: Check this video about how to add site map https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=euD5P1LBpuQ&t=35s https://xmlsitemapgenerator.org/